# Can I define a table's ROW_FORMAT with Slick's Table class?

Tags: scala, slick

I'm investigating the possibility of using compressed tables to save on storage space. I found https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-compression-tuning.html which shows some example code for setting it up, and I was able to reduce the size of one of the test tables from 1.6GB down to 0.5GB, using the commands shown in the linked example.

If I run `show create table my_big_compressed_table\G` in a mysql console (ok technically MariaDB, but I don't think that matters here), I get

```
CREATE TABLE `my_big_compressed_table` (
  `ID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  -- some more fields
  -- indexes, foreign keys, etc
) ENGINE=InnoDB <some stuff omitted> ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED KEY_BLOCK_SIZE=4
```

The last line is the important bit: `ROW_FORMAT` and `KEY_BLOCK_SIZE` are the magic words that turn compression on, but I can't find a way to define these with Slick.

```
class MyBigCompressedTable(tag: Tag) extends Table[...](tag, "MY_BIG_COMPRESSED_TABLE") {
  def id = column[Int]("ID", ...)
  // more fields, indexes, foreign keys
  def * = (id, ...)

  // TODO: rowFormat? keyBlockSize?
}
```

Does Slick provide a way to define the `ROW_FORMAT` and `KEY_BLOCK_SIZE` settings? If so, how? I'm hoping to avoid writing the table creation logic by hand. And FWIW, I'm currently stuck with Slick 2.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking into the code I don't think it is supported out of the box. I think you can implement it by introducing a custom "driver" that will inherit from the [`MySQLDriver`](https://github.com/slick/slick/blob/2.1.0/src/main/scala/scala/slick/driver/MySQLDriver.scala). That driver should override [`createTableDDLBuilder`](https://github.com/slick/slick/blob/2.1.0/src/main/scala/scala/slick/driver/MySQLDriver.scala#L80) to return a subclass of [`super.TableDDLBuilder`](https://github.com/slick/slick/blob/2.1.0/src/main/scala/scala/slick/driver/MySQLDriver.scala#L160) that in turn would override [`createTable`](https://github.com/slick/slick/blob/2.1.0/src/main/scala/scala/slick/driver/MySQLDriver.scala#L160) method. In that overridden `createTable` you can add some custom logic such as analyze if the `Table[_]` also implements some known marker trait and modify generated SQL accordingly.